# installing vmware tools: location of GCC binary?

Tags: gcc, virtual-machine, vmware

okay so I am trying to isntall VMware tools from the command line with the tar installer using these instructions:
http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html#wp1118025

I am installing vmware tools on lubuntu which I have running as a virtual machine using vmplayer.
After step 5, when responding the configuration questions on the screen, it said

```
the installatinon of vmware tools 9.2.3 build-1031360 for linux completed sucessfully.  you can devide to 
remove this software form your system at any time by invoking the following command:
"/usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl".
before running vmware tools for the first time, you need to configure it by invoking  the following command:
"usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want this program to invoke the command for  you now?
[yes]
```

I pressed enter and accepted the default [yes] value and now it says

```
Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following installed...
make
gcc
kernel headers of the running kernel

Searching for GCC...
the path "" is not valid path to the gcc binary. 
Would you like to change it? [yes]

What is the location of the gcc program on your machine?
```

I did

```
locate gcc
```

and found that there is a folder called /usr/lib/gcc, so I tried to put that in as the location but it says that the path "/usr/lib/gcc" is not valid path to the gcc library.
How do I find out where the gcc binary is on my machine is?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` is enough to get it working.

Comment: don't forget to first run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Worked for me. But I had to edit my /etc/apt/sources.list. My vanilla install Debian 8 kept asking me to insert the Jesse install CD-ROM, but after commenting out that line apt finally went out onto the internet and grabbed the package,

Comment: did not work for me, even if I pointed the gcc directory /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: Especially under Ubuntu 18.04 this is not enough. You need also to install gcc-8:

`sudo apt install gcc-8`

Answer (score 14):

Install prerequisites VMware Tools for LinuxOS:

If you have RHEL/CentOS:

```
yum install perl gcc make kernel-headers kernel-devel -y
```

If you have Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-server build-essential
```

- build-essential, also install: dpkg-dev, g++, gcc, lib6-dev, libc-dev, make

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/01/vmware-tools-linux-instalar-requisitos.html

Answer (score 6):

Entering:     /usr/bin/gcc     worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer. What I did was was first

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0
sudo aptitude install gcc-4.7 make linux-headers-`uname -r` -y
```

and tried it but it didn't work so I continued and did

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

after doing these two steps and trying again, it worked.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution for the same problem I am facing. I have Debian installed in a VM and its asking me to put "Official amd64 binary" in the CDROM and then press enter

Comment: @EternallyCurious see if dao2 answer works regarding the CDROM issue.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the problem with CDROM:
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

find your cdrom and comment it with #

save the changes: "cntrl + o", than exit the file: "cntrl + x"

and try to install again

Answer (score -1):

First execute this

```
sudo apt-get install gcc binutils make linux-source
```

Then run again

```
/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl
```

This is all you need to do. Now your system has the gcc make and the linux kernel sources.

Comment: Please explain with better English, and try to use proper formatting. On the top right, there is help section to teach you those.